# PDFsharp 1.32 to 1.50 update

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I just updated my PDFsharp packages from 1.32 to 1.50 and now I am getting this error that I can't convert `System.Drawing.Rectangle` to `PdfSharp.Drawing.XRect` . Is there anything I am missing or do I need to change this method base on the new package?

[image: DrawVerticalLines(graphics, page.Width, page.Height, PdfLineMarginX, PdfLineMarginY, PdfLineTopMarginY);]

```
protected void DrawVerticalLines(XGraphics graphics, double pageWidth, double pageHeight, int marginX, int marginY, int topMarginY)
        {
            
            XPen pen = new XPen(XColors.Black, 0.5);

            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(marginX, topMarginY, (int)(pageWidth - marginX * 2), (int)(pageHeight - marginY * 2 - topMarginY)));
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `new Rectangle(etc...` you are passing in a `System.Drawing.Rectangle` (a 'Microsoft' rectangle). That `DrawRectangle` method is expecting you to pass in a `PdfSharp.Drawing.XRect` rectangle (a 'Pdf Sharp' rectangle). Build up the Pdf Sharp rectangle and pass that in.

Comment: so would it be converted to this ? `XRect rect = new XRect(marginX, topMarginY, (int)(pageWidth - marginX * 2), (int)(pageHeight - marginY * 2 - topMarginY));`

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I'm not 100% on the constructor parameters for the XRect. What happens when you do that?